# Testing Fgrep Gives Same Results As Grep

Tags: grep

I'm trying to learn how fgrep differs from grep.  However in my test results, there is no difference.  Apparently fgrep matches on strings and ignores regex.  So I put this to the test and there was absolutely nothing that a basic fgrep can do, that grep can't.  So I can't move on, I need to understand why I have the results below, and what the difference between fgrep is, since I categorically **cannot** see any difference in any test result.

```
$ cat testfile
subscribe|unsubscribe
@lp1n3

$ grep 'subscribe|unsubscribe' testfile
subscribe|unsubscribe
$ fgrep 'subscribe|unsubscribe' testfile
subscribe|unsubscribe

$ grep '@lp1n3' testfile
@lp1n3
$ fgrep '@lp1n3' testfile
@lp1n3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it helpful to add the `-o` switch to make it easier to see what's happening:

```
$ grep -o 'subscribe|unsubscribe' testfile
subscribe|unsubscribe
```

Here we are using `grep` in Basic Regular Expression mode, where `|` is not special (it would need to be escaped `\|` to mean `OR`), so the pattern is matched as a single string

```
$ grep -oE 'subscribe|unsubscribe' testfile
subscribe
unsubscribe
```

Here we have switched to Extended Regular Expression (ERE) mode, where `|` is a regex special character, so we are matching two patterns, `subscribe` and `unsubscribe`

```
$ grep -oF 'subscribe|unsubscribe' testfile
subscribe|unsubscribe
```

Now we are matching in fixed string mode (like `fgrep`) and as expected `|` is not special - just like BRE.

`fgrep` is an (officially, [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383448/why-is-direct-invocation-as-either-egrep-or-fgrep-deprecated)) equivalent of `grep -F` so it behaves exactly the same:

```
$ fgrep -o 'subscribe|unsubscribe' testfile
subscribe|unsubscribe
```

As far as I know, `@` isn't special in either BRE or ERE, so will always give the same result as `fgrep` or `grep -F`.

Comment: Not sure if I made my question clear.  My question is what's the difference between fgrep and grep, because my testing shows that there is no difference.

Comment: @johnsmith sorry I should have mentioned - `fgrep` is equivalent to `grep -F` (I have edited the answer to make that clearer)